# Onload of form, have certain radio buttons selected

Tags: c#, forms, radio-button, onload

I have 2 forms. I would like to check a radio button as soon as I load another form (the button is in the second form). I tried

```
OnLoad(radioButton2.Checked)
```

but it hasnt worked. Any ideas?

Comment: You should name your radio buttons.

Comment: Any particular reason you wouldn't just set the Checked property to True in the designer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a radio button on one of your forms (let's refer to it as `form1` so we can distinguish it), and want to alter it upon loading another form (which I'll refer here as `form2`).

There are several things you need to keep in mind:

1. You need to ensure that the button is accessible from outside `form1`. If both forms are part of the same project (which I guess it's the case), then you need to ensure that the button is one of `protected internal`, `internal`, or `public`.
2. `form1` is actually a class; but the form that shows up on your screen isn't the `form1` class itself: it is an *instance* of the class. You will need a *reference* to that instance.
3. To reach a member of an object, you use the `.` (dot) operator. For example, if your instance of `form1` was named `myForm1`, then you would need to type `myForm1.radioButton2` to refer to the radio button. When you omit the object reference, it defaults to the current object (this is, the object whose code is executing). So when you are typing code for `form1` you can omit the reference, but to access it from `form2`, you need it (otherwise, the compiler will think that you are trying to reach something named "radioButton2" within `form2`, which probably doesn't even exist).
4. A radio button's `Checked` is a *property* (more specifically, a `bool` property): you can get or set the values of properties, but refering to a property without doing anything with it is normally pointless, and on most cases won't even compile.
5. If you want to execute code in response to some event, then you need to *register* an event handler. An event handler is just a function that returns `void` and takes a couple of arguments (an `object` and an `EventArgs` or some subclass of it). Registering the handler can be done programaticaly, but you're probably better off doing it from the designer. To create and register an event handler, follow these steps:
   5.1. Select the form on the designer, and go to the Properties window.
   5.2. Switch to the events view (a small lightning icon)
   5.3. Find the event you want to handle. In this case, `OnLoad`, and double-click on it.
   5.4. Voilà! The designer has created a method stub for your new event handler, registered it for the event, and sent you into the code view so you can fill it up.

So, assuming you have the reference to your `form1` instance (I'll get into that soon), to mark the radio button you would need a statement like this:

```
myForm1.radioButton2.Checked = true;
```

This will set the `Checked` property of the `radioButton2` control contained on the `myForm1` instance of the `form1` class to `true`; which effectively makes the radio button to appear checked.

Now, to the juicy part: how to get a reference to the form? That depends on how you (or the IDE, on your behalf) created it.
If `form1` is the startup form of your application, and you are sticking to the default way to do things in Visual Studio, then take a look at the `Program` class the Studio created for your project. There should be a function there, named `Main`. At some point, you'll see a line similar to this:

```
Application.Run(new form1());
```

the `new form1()` part creates a new instance of `form1`, and passes it to `Application.Run()` (don't bother too much now about what this call does, we are only interested on the reference). The problem is that the reference is used on the fly and not saved, but we can fix that: add something like this on the `Program` class, outside `Main`:

```
internal static form1 myForm1;
```

Then replace the `Application.Run()` call with these two lines:

```
myForm1 = new form1();
Application.Run(myForm1);
```

The call will do the same thing, but by breaking it down into two steps, we got the ability to save the reference to the static field `myForm1`.
Now, from anywhere on your program, you can use `Program.myForm1` to refer to that form. So, on your OnLoad event handler in `form2`, all you need to do is:

```
Program.myForm1.radioButton2.Checked = true;
```

---

Despite all of this, if you are "calling" your `form2` from `form1`, then you can save yourself some tedious work by checking the button just before passing control to the secondary form, something like this:

```
radioButton2.Checked = true;
// Code that shows your "form2" goes here.
```

On either case, remember to replace `form1` and `form2` with the actual names of your forms.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should simply set `someRadioButton.Checked` to `true`.
There's no point in waiting for `OnLoad`.

If, for some reason, you do want to wait for the `Load` event, you need to add a handler for the event and put your code in the handler.